# Access JPEG comments in Android

Tags: android, android-image, android-library

I am searching a way to read the comments of a jpeg file in Android. With comment I mean the string i would get with rdjpegcom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now found some apache-licenced code to access the comment here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/GetJpegProperties.htm

ExifInterface was not giving me the comment I wanted.

Comment: i can read comments in your given example, but i want to edit comment segment to write my own comment.. have you any idea.?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean the EXIF metadata? You can use the `ExifInterface` class to read the EXIF metadata:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html

Comment: I think it is a different thing until I find a tag to enables getAttribute(<tag>) to give me the String I want ;-)

Comment: Yep, the .jpg "comment" defined in the JPEG spec is it's own field, not a sub-field of the EXIF data. To make it very confusing though, Windows has implemented their own extension that _is_ a sub-field of the EXIF data  ...and to be even more confusing they _also_ call it "comments". The program`rdjpegcom`-like almost all the JPEG metadata utilities- reads and writes the JPEG "comment" and is completely unaware of any "comment" inserted by Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Agree, the jpeg, comment is it's own field, not a sub-field of the EXIF data. I've been using it for decades typically one can type or paste in about five paragraphs worth of your own information and it is freely edited and read and written in plain text.   Any full featured jpeg handler should be able to edit it, which I guess kind of leaves out Android apps, I'm not sure.